# Are Swift constants lazy by default?

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization

Something I still not quite understand about Swift ... let's say I want a property that instantiates a class in a base class used for several sub classes, e.g. ...

```
let horse = Horse();
```

Is `horse` instantiated right after app/class initialisation or when the property is accessed for the first time?

On the other hand using `lazy var` guarantees that the property is only instantiated the first time it is accessed ...

```
lazy var horse = Horse()
```

But then `horse` is not a constant. So in this case if I access `horse` multiple times I would get multiple instances of `horse` created, right?

What if I wanted both, a lazy property that is also a constant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly. Say you have a class `Farm` and inside `Farm` there is `horse` property.

```
class Farm {
    let horse = Horse()
}
```

In this case `horse` property is initialized when class instance initialized. If you make it `lazy` you have to make it mutable too.

```
class Farm {
    lazy var horse = Horse()
}
```

In this case, `horse` property is initialized when it is accessed the first time. And later when it is accessed again it returns the same instance again instead of reinitializing it. But since it is a mutable property you can assign a new instance of `Horse` to it. After you assign it new value it will return this new value whenever it is accessed.

**EDIT:** If `let horse = Horse()` is defined in global space then it is lazily created at first access.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! So no way of creating a lazy constant. But good to know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a bit late, but I think you can create a `lazy` property *as constant* using `private(set)` . Consider the example below :

```
import Foundation

struct GPS: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("GPS Initialised")
    }

    var description: String {
        return name
    }
}

struct Car {
    private(set) lazy var gps = GPS(name: "One")

    init() {
        print("Car Initialised")
    }
}

var someCar = Car()
print(someCar.gps) // Comment/Uncomment this to see lazy in action
//someCar.gps = GPS("Two") // This will create a compilation error
//
```

However, if you remove the `private(set)`, it(*gps* variable inside *Car*) will become a *variable* again which can be mutated.

You can uncomment the last line after removing the `private(set)` to verify the same

Comment: well, it's not _exactly_ a constant, it can still be modified inside the class itself ;)